# langston's ant no real behavior

Tags: javascript, html

This example was on a channel called Code Train. He wrote it quickly 
in Java. I am trying to create something similar with HTML canvas.
Here is what I have:

```
    // Not Quite Langton's Ant Coding Challenge

    <canvas id= "gc" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html"; charset="utf8">
    </head>
    <script>

    ANTW=ANTH=4;

    ANTX=ANTY=200;

    v=5;

    DIR=[1,2,3,4,5];

    window.onload=function() {
      c=document.getElementById('gc');
      cc=c.getContext('2d');
      setInterval(update,1000/100);

      ANTX=c.width/2;
      ANTY=c.height/2;

    }

    function update() {

      ANTX+=0;
      ANTY-=5;
      DIR=1;

      if (DIR === 1) {
        DIR+=1;
        ANTX+=0;
        ANTY+=5;
        turnRight();
      } else if (DIR === 2) {
        DIR+=1;
        ANTX-=5;
        ANTY+=0;
        turnRight();
      } else if (DIR === 3) {
        DIR+=1;
        ANTX+=0;
        ANTY-=5;
        turnRight();
      } else if (DIR === 4) {
        DIR+=1;
        ANTX+=5;
        ANTY+=0;
        turnRight();
      }

      if (ANTX > c.width-5) {
        ANTX=5;
      } else if (ANTX < 5) {
        ANTX=c.width-5;
      } else if (ANTY > c.height-5) {
        ANTY=5;
      } else if (ANTY < 5) {
        ANTY=c.height-5;
      }


      function turnRight() {

        if (DIR > 4

) {
      DIR-=4;
    }
  return DIR;
  }

  cc.fillStyle='black';
  cc.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
  cc.fillStyle='red';
  cc.fillRect(ANTX-ANTW/2,ANTY-ANTH/2,ANTW,ANTH);

}
</script>
```

For quite some time as I worked with it, the red ant staying in 
the center of the field. As I worked with it, it began moving 
down. Later it moved to the left. For a time it seemed lost at 
at the lower left corner.
Why won't updates catch it in its state and make it turn?
Thanks.

Comment: You are redefining your `ANTX`, `ANTY` and `DIR` variables every time update runs. You explicitly set `DIR` to 1 before your big if/else. Since you don't use `var`, they are hoisted to the global context, but you are still overriding any globals with recreated local copies right? I think you want those variables defined outside your update method.

Comment: @arbuthnott It has a home at: [GitHub JavaScript,NotQuite...](https://github.com/DangerousTod/javascript/tree/master) It is in an error state, but I have to work on something else at the moment.